# log(n)^k = O(n^epsilon)

Tags: asymptotics, computer-science

Hey I need to prove that for k >= 1 and for $0< \epsilon < 1$:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{(\log{n})^k}{n^\epsilon} < \infty$$
I should be able to do this without L'Hopitals but couldn't do it without it. can someone give a hint?

Answer (score 0):

Try substituting $n = e^m$, and consider making use of the series expansion of $e^m$ to give a desired bound.

Comment: There's probably easier solution, this question is from CS class which assumes no high level knowledge in maths. Also, I should be able to prove it in no more than 4 lines